# In google app engine how can we automatically scale based on number of tasks in pull queue

Tags: google-app-engine

We have some tasks in pull queue.If tasks increases in pull queue,we have to increase instances.How can we handle this in google app engine.

Answer (score 0):

Your app can keep track of how many tasks are in the queue via a counter:

- increment the counter when a task is added to the queue
- decrease the counter when a task is leased and/or deleted from the queue

When adding tasks and the counter is already above some threshold value then spinup another instance.

When deleting tasks if the counter is below a certain threshold then signal shutting down of a running instance.

Of course, this is just a basic logic, it needs padding with some timers or delays to account for the time it takes from an instance spinup/shutdown until it becomes effective on the counter value, graceful instance shutdown if needed, maybe track leased tasks as well, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Appengine should do the scaling (launching more instances) for you. More tasks in the queue means more requests/sec which should automatically launch more instances to handle the load.